# Delete lines in files excluding a matching pattern in linux

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with its contents

```
apple
ball
....
....
....
cat 
dog
```

from this, I want to get everything between lines with `ball` and `cat`, including `ball` but not `cat`. How can I accomplish it? I used the command `sed -n '/ball/,/cat/ p' filename`, but it would print out `ball` as well which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/cat/{found=""} /ball/{found=1} found' Input_file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/ball/,/cat/{/cat/!p;}' Input_file
```